# Laravel SOAP Authenciation

Tags: laravel, soap

I am using Laravel SOAP Wrapper to intergrate a SOAP API in my application:

https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

Except I get quite confused when I have to login to the API, see my code below. I always get a false credentials error, while it works perfectly fine in a online SOAP client.

```
$request = $this->soapWrapper->add('Auto', function ($service) {
$service
    ->wsdl('WSDL URL')                 // The WSDL url
    ->trace(true)            // Optional: (parameter: true/false)
    ->cache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE) // Optional: Set the WSDL cache
    // Optional: Set some extra     options
    ->options([
        'username' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx'
    ]);
});

  // dd($request);

    // Without classmap
$response = $this->soapWrapper->call('Auto.method', [
  'username' => 'xxx', 
  'password'   => 'xxx', 
]);

dd($response);
```

The SOAP:

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="wdsl url">
<s:element name="method">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="credentials" type="tns:credentials"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="credentials">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: is username/password the only auth?